# random integer in scheme

Tags: random, scheme, racket, mit-scheme

> In my OO World, I have an instance of "weapon" class called "max-damage". I asked to create a random number for a variable called "damage".
>
> It says: The amount of "damage" suffered should be a **random integer** no more than the "max-damage", and at least 1.
>
> I need some help to create that random integer, thanks!

PS: I can't ask more questions, in order to ask this question, I have changed the previous one, sorry..

Comment: I'm confused, why does remainder-list return a list that is not actually remainder values? Filter is a good approach to the problem, but generally you define the specific filter you want to use on the input like in Oscar's answer rather than trying to prepare the list to be filtered. It prevents you from having to transverse the list more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You got the syntax of [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) wrong, it's necessary that you pass a *procedure* as the first argument. Concretely, the procedure is a predicate (meaning: it evaluates to a boolean value), and the output list will only keep the elements in the original list that evaluate to `#t` when passed to the procedure. This is what I mean:

```
(define (remove-divisible lst value)
  (filter (lambda (x) (not (zero? (remainder x value))))
          lst))
```

If using a `lambda` bothers you, it's always possible to define a helper procedure, like this:

```
(define (remove-divisible lst value)
  (define (not-divisible? x)
    (not (zero? (remainder x value))))
  (filter not-divisible? lst))
```